# I have written this code for conversion from binary to decimal, but not getting the output. Nothing is printing on screen

Tags: c

//After entering the value of "bin", I am not getting any output. Please help me out with this.I have added "bin=bin/10;" but still problem is not solved.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>

int main()
{
    int ar[20],bin,i=0,sum=0,j,c;
    printf("Enter a Binary number\n");
    scanf("%d",&bin);
    while(bin!=0||bin!=1)
    {
        c=bin%10;
        ar[i]=c;
        i++;
    }
    ar[i]=c;

    for(j=0;j<=i;j++)
    {
        sum=sum+(ar[j]*pow(2,j));
    }
    printf("%d",sum);
    return 0;
}
```

Update: The while-loop now looks like this:

```
    while(bin!=0||bin!=1)
    {
        c=bin%10;
        ar[i]=c;
        bin=bin/10;
        i++;
    }
```

Comment: All of `ar` elements will get the same value assigned as `bin` never changes.

Comment: Your title suggest an input like `1001` and an output: `9`. Is that what you want? In that case your program is far from that.

Comment: I have updated the CODE, pls check again.

Comment: Compile the code adding symbols, run it using a debugger, step through the code line by line, inspecting the values of all relevant variables to learn what is really going on.

Comment: I adjusted you last update, to still show the original code, as if it wouldn't be around anymore, this would render given answers/comment ununderstandable.

Answer (score 2):

This line

```
while(bin!=0||bin!=1)
```

will cause an endless loop as

```
bin!=0 || bin!=1
```

will always evaluate `true` due to the use of `||`

In words: `bin` will always be either different from 0 **or** different from 1.

Example:

> If `bin` is 2 both parts will be `true`
>
> If `bin` is 1 the first part will be `true` and you get `true` due to the or (`||`)
>
> If `bin` is 0 the first part will be `false` but the second will be `true` and you get `true` due to the or (`||`)

Maybe you wanted an and, i.e. `&&`, instead of `||`

Further you must change the value of `bin` inside the loop. If you don't, that will also cause a endless loop.

From your title it seems you want something completely different than your current code. Maybe something like:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int main()
{
  char input[100];
  int value = 0;

  printf("Input a binary: ");
  if (fgets(input, 100, stdin) == NULL) // Read a whole line of input
  {
    printf("error\n");
    return 0;
  }

  char* t = input;
  while (*t == '0' || *t == '1')  // Repeat as long as input char is 0 or 1
  {
    value = value*2;              // Multiply result by 2 as this is binary conversion
    value = value + *t - '0';     // Add value of current char, i.e. 0 or 1
    ++t;                          // Move to the next char
  }

  printf("Decimal value: %d\n", value);

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: @RohitVishwakarma - Then there is more than 1 bug ;-)

Comment: can you pls copy my code in your PC and try to run.

Comment: input 1000. output 8

Answer (score 1):

[too long for a comment]

Ok, again:

The while-loop should loop as long as `(bin!=0||bin!=1)` is true.

This means it should break on the opposite:

```
!(bin!=0||bin!=1)
```

Applying [De Morgan's Law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws) we find the above is equivalent to:

```
(bin==0 && bin==1)
```

Looking at the above closely we see that to be true it is requires `bin` to be equal to 0 and 1 at the same time. This is not possible. So the loop will never end.

Comment: Previously I have missed a statement "bin=bin/10;" but now I have added. pls check again.

Answer (score 0):

Your code runs into an infinite loop.

```
while(bin!=0||bin!=1)
{
    c=bin%10;
    ar[i]=c;
    i++;
}
```

You must update your value of bin as

```
bin = bin/10;
```

I've edited your code. Here, have a look

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>
int main()
{
int ar[20],bin,i=0,sum=0,j,c;
printf("Enter a Binary number\n");
scanf("%d",&bin);
while(bin!=0)
{
    c=bin%10;
    ar[i]=c;
    i++;
    bin = bin/10;
}
//ar[i]=c;

for(j=0;j<i;j++)
{

    sum=sum+(ar[j]*pow(2,j));
}
printf("%d",sum);
return 0;

}
```

Comment: @RohitVishwakarma Your while condition is wrong. Try removing bin!=1

This would only resolve your looping error. Your logic is wrong. I'd suggest you to have better look at your logic.